# Getting error while installing react-redux@5.0.7 for react

Tags: reactjs, npm, redux, react-redux, npm-install

[Screenshot of error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fC4hL.jpg)

I tried to installed it without mentioning the version 5.0.7 and it installed properly.

Here are my dependencies:

- "react": "^17.0.1",
- "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
- "react-popper": "^1.3.7",
- "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
- "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
- "redux": "^3.7.2"

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! The error log says it all. Read it carefully: `react-redux@5.0.7` expects a peer dependency `react` you have not installed (it does not expect version 17 of React). PS: Peer dependencies are dependencies you have to install yourself.

Comment: you can give more information

Comment: Also, please do _not_ install React-Redux v5.x.  The current version is 7.2.2, and you should be using that.